# How to obtain the distribution of idmax-idmin in timeseries data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series, dataframe

This is a simplified look of my data:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close
2005-09-06 09:00:00  1234.25  1234.50  1234.00  1234.25
2005-09-06 12:00:00  1234.50  1234.75  1234.25  1234.50
2005-09-06 16:00:00  1234.50  1234.50  1234.25  1234.50
2005-09-07 09:00:00  1234.25  1234.50  1234.00  1234.25
2005-09-07 12:00:00  1234.25  1234.50  1234.25  1234.50
2005-09-07 16:00:00  1234.25  1234.75  1234.25  1234.25
2005-09-08 09:00:00  1234.25  1234.25  1234.00  1234.25
2005-09-08 12:00:00  1234.25  1234.25  1233.75  1234.25
2005-09-08 16:00:00  1234.25  1234.50  1234.00  1234.00
```

I would like to obtain, for every single day, the hour of the max and the min. The max, would be the max of the column 'High', the min would be the min of the column 'Low'. In this example the output would be:

```
           Max_Time  Min_Time    
2005-09-06 12:00:00  09:00:00
2005-09-07 16:00:00  09:00:00
2005-09-08 16:00:00  12:00:00
```

Since this summary will be pretty long, it will be useful to summarize it in order to get the distribution per timestamp, but using hourly bins, so it would look like:

```
          Max  Min
09:00:00   0    2  
12:00:00   1    1
16:00:00   2    0
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the index is already a DatetimeIndex, I would try something like:

```
>>> g = df.groupby(df.index.date) # groupby date
>>> max_min = pd.DataFrame({'Max_Time': g['High'].idxmax().dt.time, 
                            'Min_Time': g['Low'].idxmin().dt.time})
>>> max_min
            Max_Time  Min_Time
2005-09-06  12:00:00  09:00:00
2005-09-07  16:00:00  09:00:00
2005-09-08  16:00:00  12:00:00
```

(If you just want the hour, rather than the full time, you could use `dt.hour`.)

To get the individual counts for the times in each column, you can call `pd.value_counts`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'Max': max_min.Max_Time.value_counts(), 
                  'Min': max_min.Min_Time.value_counts()})
          Max  Min
09:00:00  NaN    2
12:00:00    1    1
16:00:00    2  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

We'll start with the data in `dat`. I just copied your data to experiment.

You'll want to group your dataframe by the date in the index, as you want mins and maxes for each date. This can be done by the following:

```
gb=dat.groupby(dat.index.date)
```

Then, since you want to find the index of each min and max, you can use idxmax and idxmin on each groupby series (gb.High and gb.Low) to get the index of the max and min for each date. These will, at first, include both the date and the time, as they are both in the index. You can use `.dt.time` to get just the time out of them.

```
mm=pd.DataFrame({ 'Max_Time': gb.High.idxmax().dt.time, 
                  'Min_Time': gb.Low.idxmin().dt.time } )
```

`mm` here will be the first thing you wanted. Now, to get the counts, value_counts on each column will give you the a series of times and the number of times that time shows up. However, it won't include times that never show up in the max/min, so when you combine the max and min counts into a dataframe, you'll get some NaN values. You can use fillna to remove these and replace them with 0.

```
pd.DataFrame( { 'Max': mm.Max_Time.value_counts(), 
                'Min': mm.Min_Time.value_counts() } ).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Heh - our answers are the same :-)

Comment: Essentially, yes: it seems there is exactly one obvious way to do this, and apparently one particular minute that is best for posting it.